# Compare string of bits with elements of a table python

Tags: python

I have a string of bits like this:

```
"1000101101000111000011101000001001111000"
```

and a table like this:

```
[[97, '11'], 
 [111, '10'], 
 [32, '010'], 
 [115, '011'], 
 [100, '0011'], 
 [108, '0010'], 
 [110, '0001'], 
 [114, '0000']]
```

I would like to code the string with the int values (97,111,32,...) but every time I only get [111,108] because it's not coming back and only adds positions. Can anyone help me understand why? This is what I have:

```
array_final = []
posSeg = 0
for i in range(len(tabela)):
    if arrayJunto[posSeg:(posSeg+len(tabela[i][1]))]==tabela[i][1]:
        array_final.append(tabela[i][0])
        posSeg += len(tabela[i][1])
```

Comment: Are you trying something in the lines of Huffman encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, leaving those pairs of values in `tabela` is unwise - a dictionary mapping is a much easier way to code this:

```
map_dict = dict((t[1], t[0]) for t in tabela)
```

which gives:

```
map_dict == {'0010': 108, '0011': 100, '0001': 110, 
             '0000': 114, '10': 111, '11': 97, 
             '011': 115, '010': 32}
```

Secondly, you are iterating over the length of `tabela`, *not* `arrayJunto`. It should look like:

```
while posSeg < len(arrayJunto):
    for key in map_dict:
        if arrayJunto[posSeg:posSeg + len(key)] == key:
            posSeg += len(key)
            array_final.append(map_dict[key])
            break
    else:
        break
```

The two `break`s ensure that:

1. You don't find multiple matches for the same characters; and
2. You don't get stuck in an infinite loop if nothing matches.

This gives me:

```
array_final == [111, 108, 97, 32, 100, 111, 110, 97, 32, 114, 111, 115, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, hope it helps :

```
t = [[97, '11'], 
    [111, '10'], 
    [32, '010'], 
    [115, '011'], 
    [100, '0011'], 
    [108, '0010'], 
    [110, '0001'], 
    [114, '0000']]
>>> s =""
>>> for l in t: s += str(l[0])
... 
>>> s
'9711132115100108110114'
```